# error getting arguments from angularjs in php

Tags: php, angularjs

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$username=$data->username;
$password=$data->password;
```

I am getting error :
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$username in login.php 
fail

angularjs code:

```
var url="login.php";

//post the username & password 
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:{'username':log.username,
          'password':log.password}
})
```

any help? I'm new to angularjs
am I doing something wrong with getting the arguments?

Ty for your help

Comment: did you try to var_dump your php input ? what do you have ?

Comment: did u try `$_POST['username'];` ?

Comment: response for $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];   Notice: Undefined index: username in login.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: password in login.php on line 5
fail

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code by replacing http with ajax

var url="login.php";

```
    //post the username & password 
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:{'username':log.username,
              'password':log.password}
    })
```

Comment: when using your code :ReferenceError: $ is not defined tough i added jquery to the scripts..